# Simple FB inquiry: FB login screen in a canvas app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Rails app runs in a FB canvas. The problem:

If the user isn't logged in to Facebook, there is a redirect to the Facebook login / auth page. However, that doesn't work in the canvas, because the facebook auth page doesn't allow itself to be loaded into an iframe. This is the console error:

`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

So users can't log in to FB to auth the app. It works fine when not running in the canvas.

How can I fix this?

## Solved

Added `:target => "_top"` to the link and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `:target => "_top"` to the link and it works fine now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, which link did you add this too?