# append target to url

Tags: java, html

I don't have a physical page with a link, but rather an application that is firing the link from the backend using `java.net.URL`. I'm wondering how I can append `target=_top` to the URL? I feel like I've tried everything but have failed. Could some one please help me. Perhaps there's away to set it in `java.net.URL too`.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=111111111&redirect_uri=https://local.example.com:8443/test/facebook/oauth/blank/https:$002f$002flocal.example.com:8443$002ftest$002fsignin/target=_top
```

is one of the cases I've tried without success.

I've tried all the following as well.

```
:target=_top
/target=_top
&target=_top

:target="_top"
/target="_top"
&target="_top"
```

the issue I'm facing [Simple FB inquiry: FB login screen in a canvas app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628467/simple-fb-inquiry-fb-login-screen-in-a-canvas-app)

Some code

**Attempt 1**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=");
        sb.append(getOauthClientId());
        sb.append("&target=_top");
        sb.append("&redirect_uri=");
        sb.append(getOauthRedirectLink());        
        sb.append("&scope=");
        sb.append(facebookPermissions);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return new URL(sb.toString());
```

**Attempt 2**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=");
        sb.append(getOauthClientId());        
        sb.append("&redirect_uri=");
        sb.append(getOauthRedirectLink());        
        sb.append("&scope=");
        sb.append(facebookPermissions);
        sb.append("&target=_top");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return new URL(sb.toString());
```

My goal is to fire this link off from the backend rather than using javascript to trigger the link.

Comment: please, provide a code. what have you tried and what result do you expect

Comment: @ursa I added a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
URI.create(sb.toStrgin()).toURL();
```

Correct way:

- use URI builders, e.g. [javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) or [org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) or something similar.

Comment: still no success even setting target right after ? mark, any additional thoughts?

Comment: do you have **working** uri you want to receive? maybe the problem is not in building, but in fact your target uri is incorrect?

Comment: It works perfectly if I have an anchor tag with the target attribute set to _top. I'm just trying to do this without a user having to click the link, but the iframe within facebook is causing issues. From facebook Because your game is loaded in an iframe, returning a 302 to redirect the user to the Login Dialog will be unsuccessful. Instead you must target the top (or _top) frame for redirect, which causes the parent window to redirect to the Login Dialog URL.

Comment: No, browser does NOT read this parameter. You need to use JS.

Comment: Ah okay, well that seems to be the problem. I thought maybe there was away to tell the browser to target through the url. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.URL` provides a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.net.URL-java.lang.String-) wherein you can append a `String` to a `URL`.

Try this:

```
URL fbook = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("authorize?client_id=");
sb.append(getOauthClientId());  
sb.append("&redirect_uri=");
sb.append(getOauthRedirectLink());        
sb.append("&scope=");
sb.append(facebookPermissions);
sb.append("&target=_top");
URL n = new URL(fbook,sb.toString());
```

Comment: That seems to chop the url up like so https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/&target=_top Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I was hoping there would be away to trigger the browser to target top, but it doesn't look like its possible. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Is the application backend implemented in core java or are you using some kind of framework?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65923/discussion-between-ravtej-singh-and-code-junkie).